# Audio format that keeps separate tracks

Tags: software, recommendations, multichannel, format

I'm looking for a way to render a 4-channel audio file where the channels are mapped to stereo, that is, two of the channels play on the right channel and two on the left.

When I make a 4-channel file in OGG or WAV, the two first channels are joined as a stereo track and the other two become mono (image below). But I wanted the other two to also be joined in a stereo track.

In other words, I don't really need a 4-channel file, but rather an audio format that allows to keep separate tracks.

[image]

Comment: What's your use-case for this? If you want output to two channels why not just save as stereo file?

Comment: Because I want to keep the tracks separate (let's say I want to isolate one of the tracks later).

Comment: What are you playing back from that can handle 4 independently-panned channels? This sounds like some kind of [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: this looks more like an issue with audacity - I am fairly sure WAV format doesn't distinguish between 'types' of track, just the overall number of tracks in a poly file.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a multi-tracks audacity project as a multichannel wav file. For this, you need to activate the *use advanced mixing options* in the [Import/Export preference pane](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/import_export_preferences.html). You will then be offered a channel mapping option when exporting audio.

(Notice that such a four channel file would not be played as two stereo track in most players).